# Pass Multiple Arguments to Bash Script

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a bash script, which I want to call like this:

```
bash curl.sh http://www.google.co.uk/ -d Directory -a "Moz 123" -r http://localhost/
```

I can collect the first argument (http://www.google.co.uk/), with the following:

```
url=$1
while getopts p:d:a:r: opt; do
case $opt in
    p) proxy=$OPTARG ;;
    d) dir=$OPTARG ;;
    a) ua=$OPTARG ;;
    r) ref=$OPTARG ;;
esac
done
```

However, it does not pick up the other -arguments. If I remove 'http://www.google.co.uk/' as the first argument, it picks up the -arguments.

Due to logistics, I am not able to set the first argument, e.g. 'http://www.google.co.uk/' with -u etc.

How do you get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this seems the best option:

Call the script like:

```
bash curl.sh -d Remote -a "Moz 123" -r http://localhost http://www.google.com/
```

You can pick the last argument up like:

```
url=${!#}
```

And then the other options using getopts, as above.

Answer (score 5):

Why not pass arguments in, wrapped in quotes?

e.g.

```
script.shl "http://www.google.com" "/var/www/test" "option 3"
```

...then you can just access them directly in the script using $1 $2 $3. You can still alter the course of the script by just using if...else?

Unless, I've mis-read your question...

Comment: There are multiple options that can be passed to the script, sometimes I do not use all of them. So I requite to pass them like: -a -b

Comment: ah, although you could always pass a null argument? script.shl "www,google.com" "NULL" "option 3". Then just add a clause to ignore if "NULL" is found...

Comment: This doesn't scale well for programs that could have many optional arguments. You don't want to have to call a program like `script.shl "" "foo" "" "" "bar" "" "" "" "3" "" "4"`.

Answer (score 3):

`getopts` stops parsing as soon as it sees an argument that does not begin with a hyphen. You'll have to change the order in which you pass the arguments, or use the GNU version of the external `getopt` program, which can handle regular arguments mixed in with options.

I think the following should work (it's modeled on your code and an example at http://linuxaria.com/howto/parse-options-in-your-bash-script-with-getopt?lang=en). Essentially, `getopt` just reorders the arguments and breaks apart any combine options (like changing `-xyz` to `-x -y -z`). Any non-optional arguments will be found after `--` in the parsed option list.

```
PARSED_OPTIONS=$( getopt -o "p:d:a:r:" -- "$@" )
eval set -- "$PARSED_OPTIONS"
while true; do
    case $1 in
        p) proxy=$2; shift 2 ;;
        d) dir=$2; shift 2 ;;
        a) ua=$2; shift 2 ;;
        r) ref=$2; shift 2;;
        --) shift; break ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Are you able to reference some code where I can see this in use with regular arguments and options?